# Learning MPI Implementation

Tags: mpi, message-queue, hpc, nic

What is the best way to find out how MPI is implemented?  What kind of support is there in hardware to speed up MPI?  What exactly are the features provided by a NIC? How does the MPI implementation differ from SHMEM's?

I'm also confused as to how all the implementations transfer data between the processes (shared memory, message queues, NIC, kaput, etc).

I've looked for books on the topic but all I've been able to find are books on how to 'use' MPI or on MPI algorithms.

Should I just dive in into the source code of one of the open source implementations?

Comment: Yes, you should dive into the source code of one (or more) of the open source implementations.  You should also trawl through SO and look for posts by Hristo Iliev and Jonathan Dursi who both know this sort of stuff, you'll pick up pointers from them.  Any details of MPI implementations tend to get published in research papers, conference proceedings, that sort of thing.  I can't imagine a book on the topic would sell more than about 6 copies worldwide.

Comment: To add to Mark's comment, MPI implementations tend to be very complex pieces of software, especially those parts that implement the actual data transfer. The authors usually concentrate on the efficiency and not on the clarity of the code. If you decide to look at some implementation's source, I would recommend that you start with MPICH, since it is more monolithic and somehow easier to follow than the component architecture of Open MPI. Also note that your question is off-topic on Stack Overflow - it is too general and does not address a specific programming problem.

Comment: It would also be worthwhile to read basically the entire archive of Jeff Squyres 'Cisco HPC' blog, http://blogs.cisco.com/tag/hpc/

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of resources that I would recommend:

1. Official [MPI Forum Documents](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/), including MPI Specifications for current and older versions.
2. [OpenMPI Papers](http://www.open-mpi.org/papers/) - A few interesting papers on implementations and low level communication &c.
3. [MPICH Source](http://www.mpich.org/downloads/) (Following Hirsto Iliev's comment)
4. [OpenMPI Source Code](http://www.open-mpi.org/svn/)